# Can I make a constraint in MySQL over multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```sql
create table hospitals (
    id varchar(6),
    url varchar(2048),
    primary key (id)
);
```

```sql
create table rates (
    hospital_id varchar(6),
    rate decimal(6,2),
    primary key (hospital_id, rate)
);
```

I want a constraint which satisfies the following:

"If a `(hospital_id, rate)` pair is added to the `rates` table, then the corresponding url in the hospitals table must be NOT NULL"

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The model as presented does not make a whole lot of sense. Could you provide a bit more context for it?

Comment: @mustaccio can you explain why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Because your model does not represent any real-life entities I'm familiar with, and you don't say _what exactly_ it represents. An alternative explanation, which is also plausible, is that I am intellectually incapable of comprehending it.

Comment: @mustaccio it's not about smart or not smart. I'm dealing with a niche scenario where I'm running a data bounty with a distributed database Dolt, that works like git. I want to add sanity checks to make sure the bounty hunters don't insert junk into the database. If they insert into the `rates` table I want them to also have inserted a corresponding URL so that I can check what they've inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with triggers. Make it `before insert`, so it would trigger before insert. In the trigger, check the condition. If condition is good, just end the trigger, if bad - throw error with `signal`.

You would have something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON rates FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

if (select url from hospitals where id=NEW.hospital_id) is null then
   signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'My Error Message';
end if;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the columns in a `PRIMARY KEY` are automatically forced to be `NOT NULL` during `CREATE TABLE`.  So, I don't know what the problem is.

Furthermore, you may want a `FOREIGN KEY` to automatically validate that the `hospitals.id` is not missing from `hospitals` when `INSERTing` a `hospital_id` into `rates`.